Spacing of \part over two lines (using classicthesis
I'm using classicthesis, which has a pretty layout for \part in a book class.
I was hoping to display the title of a part over two lines. Using \\ immediatly gives an error. Using \newline works, but gives rather strange spacing.
The TeX code is
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}
       
\tableofcontents

\part[First line (Second line)]{First line \newline (Second line)}

\end{document}



Please, add a minimal example from \documentclass to \end{document}.

You can protect \\  from the case change macros.

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\part[First line (Second line)]{First line \NoCaseChange{\\}(Second line)}

\end{document}


Wow! So what exactly does TeX internally change \\\ to in the original code?

@Krijn \centering  redefines \\  to make a centered newline but \newline  for historical reason sisn't changed (so does not produce centered lines after the line break) so this reverts to \\  but protects it from \MakeUppercase

I'm trying this solution \NoCaseChange{\\} in Overleaf (because my thesis takes long too compile), but there it gives a similar error as the original code \\ 

However, on overleaf this can be solved with \MakeLowercase{\\} 

@Krijn the version posted works in an up to date tex system, but there have been some changes in that area so glad you found a way to adjust things on older systems
